# Getting a RecyclerView to reload items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, xamarin.android

I am currently working on an app, that finds all MP3s on a users phone and then puts them into a list. This works very fine and is very quick, even with many songs. Now I populate a new list with an object for each item of the list to then display it inside my recyclerview. The problem is, that I have 700+ songs on my phone and this blocks the UI thread quite some time.

Now, I want to use the recyclerview to not load all items from the list into the objects all at once but rather only when they are about to be displayed - but I have NO clue over how to do this. Right now, all objects are build and then displayed in a very long scrollview from the recyclerview after the UI thread has been blocked for a good 30 seconds. Can please anyone help me? Here is my code:

```
namespace Media_Player
{
    [Activity(Label = "Media_Player", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        static public MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
        List<MP3object> mp3;
        MediaMetadataRetriever reader;
        public static Button btn_StartOrPause, btn_Stop;
        public static TextView txt_CurrentSong;
        public static bool stopIsActive = false, firstStart = true;
        public static Android.Net.Uri CurrentActiveSongUri;

        RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
        PhotoAlbumAdapter mAdapter;


        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.test);

            reader = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
            PopulateMP3List(ReturnPlayableMp3(true));
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

            InitRecView();
        }

        private void InitRecView()
        {

            // Instantiate the adapter and pass in its data source:
            mAdapter = new PhotoAlbumAdapter(mp3);

            // Get our RecyclerView layout:
            mRecyclerView = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerView);

            // Plug the adapter into the RecyclerView:
            mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(mAdapter);

            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
            mRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        }


        private void PopulateMP3List(List<string> content)
        {
           mp3 = new List<MP3object>();        
           foreach (string obj in content)
           {
               WriteMetaDataToFileList(obj);        
           }
        }

        void WriteMetaDataToFileList(string obj)
        {
            reader.SetDataSource(obj);

            //Write Mp3 as object to global list
            MP3object ob = new MP3object();
            {
                if(reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyTitle) != "" && reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyTitle) != null)
                {
                    ob.SongName = reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyTitle);
                }
                else
                {
                    ob.SongName = Resources.GetString(Resource.String.Unknown);
                }

                if (reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyArtist) != "" && reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyArtist) != null)
                {
                    ob.ArtistName = reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyArtist);
                }
                else
                {
                    ob.ArtistName = Resources.GetString(Resource.String.Unknown);
                }

                if (reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyAlbum) != "" && reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyAlbum) != null)
                {
                    ob.AlbumName = reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyAlbum);
                }
                else
                {
                    ob.AlbumName = Resources.GetString(Resource.String.Unknown);
                }

                if (reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyYear) != "" && reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyYear) != null)
                {
                    ob.Year = reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyYear);
                }
                else
                {
                    ob.Year = Resources.GetString(Resource.String.Unknown);
                }

                if (reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyYear) != "" && reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyYear) != null)
                {
                    ob.Year = reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyYear);
                }
                else
                {
                    ob.Year = Resources.GetString(Resource.String.Unknown);
                }

                ob.Mp3Uri = obj; // can never be unknown!

                ob.DurationInSec = int.Parse(reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyDuration)) / 1000; // can never be unknown, div by 1000 to get sec not millis
            }
            mp3.Add(ob);

        }

        public List<string> ReturnPlayableMp3(bool sdCard)
        {
            List<string> res = new List<string>();
            string phyle;
            string path1 = null;

            if(sdCard) // get mp3 from SD card
            {
                string baseFolderPath = "";

                try
                {
                    bool getSDPath = true;

                    Context context = Application.Context;
                    Java.IO.File[] dirs = context.GetExternalFilesDirs(null);

                    foreach (Java.IO.File folder in dirs)
                    {
                        bool IsRemovable = Android.OS.Environment.InvokeIsExternalStorageRemovable(folder);
                        bool IsEmulated = Android.OS.Environment.InvokeIsExternalStorageEmulated(folder);

                        if (getSDPath ? IsRemovable && !IsEmulated : !IsRemovable && IsEmulated)
                            baseFolderPath = folder.Path;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("GetBaseFolderPath caused the following exception: {0}", ex);
                }

                string xy = baseFolderPath.Remove(18); // This is result after this, but this hard coded solution could be a problem on different phones.: "/storage/05B6-2226/Android/data/Media_Player.Media_Player/files"

                path1 = xy;
                // path to SD card and MUSIC "/storage/05B6-2226/"
            }
            else // get Mp3 from internal storage
            {
                    path1 = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.ToString();
            }

            var mp3Files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path1, "*.mp3", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            foreach (string currentFile in mp3Files)
            {
                phyle = currentFile;
                res.Add(phyle);
            }

            return res;
        }


    }

    public class PhotoViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public ImageView Image { get; private set; }
        public TextView Caption { get; private set; }

        public PhotoViewHolder(View itemView) : base(itemView)
        {
            // Locate and cache view references:
            Image = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView);
            Caption = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView);
        }
    }

    public class PhotoAlbumAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
    {
        public List<MP3object> mp3;
        public PhotoAlbumAdapter(List<MP3object> mp3)
        {
            this.mp3 = mp3;
        }

        public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).
                        Inflate(Resource.Layout.lay, parent, false);
            PhotoViewHolder vh = new PhotoViewHolder(itemView);
            return vh;
        }

        public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {
            PhotoViewHolder vh = holder as PhotoViewHolder;
            vh.Caption.Text = mp3[position].SongName;
        }

        public override int ItemCount
        {
            get { return mp3.Count(); }
        }
    }



}
```

So getting the list of strings with the locations of the Mp3 works very quickly, but then "WriteMetaDataToFileList(obj)" kicks in, comming from "PopulateMP3List(List content)" and this is what takes so long. What I think I need is for the recyclerview to only build the first 20 objects, and when the user starts scrolling, builds the next 20 objects and attaches them to list for them to also be scrolled. Please help me out here :)

Comment: Simply use the `OnBindViewHolder` method, and place the code you want to be executed "only when the object is about to be displayed" inside it.

Comment: So, I let only the first 10 items loaded, and once they are displayed this method is called so I continue to load the next 10 items? thank you.

Comment: (Edited the above comment). The `onBindViewHolder` gets called when a object is attached to list. So, basically just before the object-view is actually displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an abstract class:

```
public abstract class PaginationScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {
private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;

protected PaginationScrollListener(LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager) {
    this.linearLayoutManager = linearLayoutManager;
}

@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
    int visibleItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getChildCount();
    int totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
    int firstVisibleItemPosition = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
    if (!isLoading() && !isLastPage()) {
        if ((visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItemPosition) >= totalItemCount && firstVisibleItemPosition >= 0) {
            loadMoreItems();
        }
    }
}

protected abstract void loadMoreItems();

public abstract boolean isLastPage();

public abstract boolean isLoading();
}
```

and In your adapter you must follow this pattern:

```
public class ConsultancyAdapter extends      RecyclerView.Adapter<ConsultancyAdapter.ConsultancyVH> {
private static final int ITEM = 0;
private static final int LOADING = 1;
private boolean isLoadingAdded = false;

public ConsultancyAdapter(List<Consultancy> consultancies, ConsultancyAdapterListener listener) {
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ConsultancyVH onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    switch (viewType) {
        case ITEM:
            viewHolder = getViewHolder(parent, layoutInflater);
            break;
        case LOADING:
            View v2 = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_progress, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ConsultancyVH(v2);
            break;
    }
    return (ConsultancyVH) viewHolder;
}
@NonNull
private RecyclerView.ViewHolder getViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, LayoutInflater inflater) {
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;
    View v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_consultancy, parent, false);
    viewHolder = new ConsultancyVH(v1);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override

public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ConsultancyVH holder, int position) {
    Consultancy consultancy = consultancies.get(position);
    switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
        case ITEM:
            ConsultancyVH mySingeCounseller = holder;
            holder.title.setText(consultancy.getTitle());  // set cardTitle
            holder.fieldArea.setText(consultancy.getField_filedoctorskills());               

            break;
        case LOADING:
            break;
    }
}    


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return consultancies.size();
}
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return (position == consultancies.size() - 1 && isLoadingAdded) ? LOADING : ITEM;
}

public void add(Consultancy mc) {
    consultancies.add(mc);
    notifyItemInserted(consultancies.size() - 1);
}

public void addAll(List<Consultancy> mcList) {
    for (Consultancy mc : mcList) {
        add(mc);
    }
}

public void remove(Consultancy city) {
    int position = consultancies.indexOf(city);
    if (position > -1) {
        consultancies.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
}

public Consultancy getItem(int position) {
    return consultancies.get(position);
}

public void clear() {
    isLoadingAdded = false;
    while (getItemCount() > 0) {
        remove(getItem(0));
    }
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return getItemCount() == 0;
}

public void addLoadingFooter() {
    isLoadingAdded = true;
    add(new Consultancy());
}

public void removeLoadingFooter() {
    isLoadingAdded = false;

    int position = consultancies.size() - 1;
    Consultancy item = getItem(position);


    if (item != null) {
        consultancies.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
}

public interface ConsultancyAdapterListener {
    void onCaseClicked(int position, String nid, String fieldArea, String title);
}

protected class ConsultancyVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView title, fieldArea;
    private CircleImageView iconProfile;
    private MaterialRippleLayout caseButtonRipple;

    public ConsultancyVH(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        caseButtonRipple = itemView.findViewById(R.id.case_button_ripple);
        this.title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.docName);
        this.fieldArea = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fieldArea);
        this.iconProfile = itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon_profile);
    }

}
}
```

and in your activity:

```
    private void setScrollListener() {
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new PaginationScrollListener(linearLayoutManager) {
        @Override
        protected void loadMoreItems() {
            isLoading = true;
            currentPage += 1;
                    loadNextPage();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isLastPage() {
            return isLastPage;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isLoading() {
            return isLoading;
        }
    });
                    loadFirstPage();

}
```

and in my loadFirstPage i talk to a API and you need some your code:

```
private void loadFirstPage() {
    CallData().enqueue(new DefaultRetrofitCallback<List<Consultancy>>() {
        @Override
        protected void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            super.onFailure(t);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSuccess(List<Consultancy> response) {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            dataList = response;
            adapter.addAll(dataList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            if (!checkLast(response)) adapter.addLoadingFooter();
            else isLastPage = true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onOtherStatus(Response<List<Consultancy>> response) {
            super.onOtherStatus(response);
        }

        @Override
        protected void always() {
            super.always();
        }
    });
}
```

and loadNextPage:

```
private void loadNextPage() {
    CallData().enqueue(new DefaultRetrofitCallback<List<Consultancy>>() {
        @Override
        protected void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            super.onFailure(t);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSuccess(List<Consultancy> response) {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            adapter.removeLoadingFooter();
            isLoading = false;
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            adapter.addAll(response);
            if (!checkLast(response)) adapter.addLoadingFooter();
            else isLastPage = true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onOtherStatus(Response<List<Consultancy>> response) {
            super.onOtherStatus(response);
        }

        @Override
        protected void always() {
            super.always();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I don`t know that I whether I understand your problem or not? your problem is all songs show together?

Comment: No sorry. It is that the list containing all objects is massive. and for it to be done and then shown on screen a LOT of time passes and blocks the ui thread. So what I would need to do is to load only the first say 10 items, and when the recyclerview has displayed them all and reached the bottom, the next 10 items  must be loaded into the list and then displayed.

Comment: I got it, your problem will be solved with pagination, I`ll put some code for you and I hope to be useful. Pagination means that your recyclerview have some pages and when user scroll down the recycler view the device show some items and so on.

Comment: Sounds awesome. cannot wait :)

Comment: It was useful or not?

Comment: Hi there. I was in the weekend! :) I am reading it now. It is java but I will try to port it to c#. shouldnt be much of an issue, i will report back soon, thank you!